# Can an iPhone application relaunch itself when terminated?

Tags: iphone

I have two requirements for my latest project:

- When the app launches for the first time it should display the device native dialer and then check for callDidConnected in background.
- once the callDidConnected is true app should launch itself.

Here I tried the following logic:

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {


 //i am dialing to a IVR from the native dialer

 if (/* A check to validate wether to call or not */)
 {
    NSLog(@"Dialing");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:"]];


    // A loop check wether the call get connected  
    while (!callDidConnected){
  callDidConnected = // doing a check with server
    }

    // if call get connected then launching my application
    if (callDidConnected){
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MyApp:"]];
 }

 }

 else
 {
  // normal app
 }
}



 - (void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

- I registered the app with URL MyApp.
- I tested this code on simulator(on SDK 3.0/3.2) with opening another app(tried http instead of tel protocol). The check executes in background while other native app(safari) run in foreground.

  "So this look a little odd" the Apple guys says.

  Can any one help me to find whether I can use this code in my work, and will it be acceptable by Apple store.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are trying to do...
You want to open the app when it's closed? -> infinite loop. Then how to quit the app?

Comment: I sincerely hope that Apple restrict this sort of behaviour and if they don't I'm sure it won't take too long before they do.

Answer (score 8):

No this is not possible or acceptable.

Think about it: the iPhone would not be able to do anything other than run this app, since it would instantly launch again when you quit it... Sounds like malware to me. Not something I'd ever want on my iPhone, and I'm happy that Apple restrict this kind of thing.

Comment: Also, this would be rendered effectively useless by iOS 4.0's multitasking functionality, since you could just as easily send it to the background using the home button and go to another application.

Comment: While for app store use I agree with you @Jasarien what about if you are wanting to use the iPhone or iPad as a kiosk? This would be perfect for those if it will work. If you need to truly exit the app then you take it out of the kiosk and do a reboot and it will stay out of the app. Although the original poster seemed concerned about Apple approval so I don't think that this is the case.

Comment: @jamone If a kisosk is the situation, the iPad/iPhone's home button should be covered to prevent it from being pressed.